# Avro schema definition with two primitive types

Tags: avro

Can I define an avro schema with 2 primitve types? Like so:

```
{ "type": "record"
  "name": "MyData",
   "fields" : [
              {"name":"my_number","type":["int","long"]}, <<<<< THIS
              {"name":"my_string","type":["null","string"]}
              ]
}
```

Note <<<< THIS is just to highlight how i want to define it.

Or since I could get long values I should just use long?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this sort of type is known as a Union, see https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/spec.html#Unions